# Show into div elements from http request js

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a problem and I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this. I am new to javascript and I made an HTTP request to a server to get some data and now I want to display the data into a div in HTML. I tried to use createElement to display the text and the image of what I want to see in HTML but with no luck. Can someone please help me? Thanks for your time in advance.

js code

```
var displaySoccerApi = document.getElementById("socceApi");

const api_url =
  "https://mysoccerapi.com";

// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
  // Storing response
  const response = await fetch(url);

  // Storing data in form of JSON
  var data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  //   if (response) {
  //     console.log("data here");
  //   }
}
// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="soccerApi"></div>
</body>
```

All I want is to show the data from the API to the div in the HTML with an image and title that the API provides. Can someone please help me?

Regards

Comment: the quoted url does not exist and nobody knows the structure of the data returned. Please add sufficient detail to allow others to deduce the answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. The data from the API is local and it's just an array with objects that has 2 keys, 1 title, 1 img, something like this:
 const soccer = [
   {
     img:
 "https://demo.jpg",
     title: "Soccer Player",  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, based upon your comment, that the data returned is of the form:

```
response=[
    {title:'Hello World',img:'/images/image1.jpg'},
    {title:'Goodbye World',img:'/images/image2.jpg'},
    {title:'Other text',img:'/images/image3.jpg'}
];
```

a simple `forEach` loop

```
response.forEach( obj=>{
    /*
        create new DOM elements
    */
    let div=document.createElement('div');
    let h1=document.createElement('h1');
    let img=new Image();
    
    div.append(h1);
    div.append(img);
    
    /*
        assign content from api data
    */
    h1.innerHTML=obj.title;
    img.src=obj.img;

    /*
        add to DOM
    */
    displaySoccerApi.append( div );
})
```

For example: A working snippet to show possibly how to use the above

```js
  var displaySoccerApi=document.getElementById('socceApi');


  var response=[
    {title:'West Bromwich Albion',img:'https://assets-sports.thescore.com/soccer/team/78/logo.png'},
    {title:'West Ham United',img:'https://assets-sports.thescore.com/soccer/team/65/logo.png'},
    {title:'Manchester City',img:'https://i2.wp.com/dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/256x256/8456/teamlogo.png'}
  ];


  response.forEach( obj=>{
    let div=document.createElement('div');
    let h1=document.createElement('h1');
    let img=new Image();

    div.append(h1);
    div.append(img);

    h1.innerHTML=obj.title;
    img.src=obj.img;
    displaySoccerApi.append( div );
  })
```

```html
<div id='socceApi'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time, I really appreciate it. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: yes it did. thank you so much, I marked your answer as the correct one. Thank you so much.